# How to test a Bus.Defer()

Tags: unit-testing, nservicebus

Does anybody know how to check (in a unit test) if a `Bus.Defer()` has happened? It seems this is not enough:

```
Test.Saga<TSaga>(mySaga).ExpectSend < MessageThatIsDeferred >()
```

The result is:

```
ExpectedSendInvocation< MessageThatIsDeferred > not fulfilled
```

Calls made:

```
DeferMessageInvocation< MessageThatIsDeferred,System.DateTime >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using a Saga, and in that case you should be calling `RequestTimeout` instead, see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas-in-nservicebus#timeouts

To test a saga timeout here is an example:

```
Test.Saga<TimeoutSaga>()
            .ExpectTimeoutToBeSetIn<MyTimeout>()
            .When(saga => saga.Handle(new StartMessage()));
```

Does this make sense ?

Comment: Yes, it seems it does make sense :). Thx